# Scroll to individual mapped header names in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a tab list of 4 names which I am mapping over the data for in the first map and I am trying to implement a link for each one so that it scrolls to the same header name in the second mapping.

The current anchor link seems to just take me to the first heading when I click on each of the tab names at the moment. I am not sure if I possibly need to use a ref to somehow get each data name to link to individually.

```
<FormGroupWrapper>
{props.groups.map((group) => {
  return (
    <DisplayNameTab>
      <a href="#heading">{group.displayNames}</a>
    </DisplayNameTab>
 )
)
</FormGroupWrapper>

<FormGroupWrapper>
{props.groups.map((group) => {
  return (
    <DisplayNameTab>
      <h1 id="heading">{group.displayNames}</h1>
      <p>{group.description}</p>
    </DisplayNameTab>
 )
)
</FormGroupWrapper>
```

Comment: What is the name of the plugin. Try and post a working example

Comment: consider using `.map((group, index))` and attach the index onto the `href` and `id` so you get `id={\`heading-${index}\`}`. This will give you a unique link + id to scroll to. Or even better, if your group has a unique ID already, use that for the `href` and `id`.